# php json to load jquery datagrid

Tags: php, json

I've this php code that passes results to a jquery getJSON function that doesn't work properly.

here is my code:

```
    $data["total"]=mysql_num_rows($s);
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {

        $ris_sql["utente"]=tv($r["utente"]);
        $ris_sql["contratto"]=tv($r["contratto"]);
        $ris_sql["login"]=tv($r["login"]);
        $ris_sql["piattaforma"]=tv($r["piattaforma"]);
        $ris_sql["azione"]=tv(format_valid($r["azione"]));
        $ris_sql["data"]=tv($r["data"]);
        $ris_sql["note"]=tv(str_replace("<br>","",$r["note"]));
        $riga[]=$ris_sql;
    }
    $data["rows"]=json_encode($riga, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

If I try to use firebug I see that my *rows* elements in JSON result like a string instead a series of objects, what is wrong in my code??

Answer (score 0):

You are double-encoding the `$riga` JSON.  Don't separately encode the `$riga` part prior to encoding the rest of the `$data` array you're sending back to the browser.

```
// Instead of
$data["rows"] = json_encode($riga, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// This double-encodes the contents of $data before outputting back to the browser or ajax call
echo json_encode($data);

// Just do:
echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

If the format isn't what you expect, instead you can cast `$riga` from an array to an `object` and then encode the whole thing without `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`.

```
// Cast $riga from an assoc array to an instance of stdClass
$data['rows'] = (object)$riga;
// And then JSON encode the whole $data
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: @haltman Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you